# Cast class with covariance in generic

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have a problem with invariance and covariance in generic and c#

I want cast handlerConcrete, here the code

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var handlerConcrete = new HandlerTestConcrete<MessageBaseTestConcrete, ResponseMessageBaseTestConcrete>() { };
        var cast = handlerConcrete as IHandlerTest<MessageBaseTest, ResponseMessageBaseTest>;
    }
}


public interface IHandlerTest<in TRequest, out TResponse>
where TRequest : MessageBaseTest
where TResponse : ResponseMessageBaseTest
{
    GenericResponse<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request);
}
public class HandlerTestConcrete<TRequest, TResponse> : IHandlerTest<TRequest, TResponse>
where TRequest : MessageBaseTest
where TResponse : ResponseMessageBaseTest
{
    public Task<GenericResponse<TResponse>> Handle(TRequest request)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ResponseMessageBaseTest { }
public class MessageBaseTest { }

public class ResponseMessageBaseTestConcrete: ResponseMessageBaseTest { }
public class MessageBaseTestConcrete: MessageBaseTest { }

public interface GenericResponse<TResponse> where TResponse : ResponseMessageBaseTest
{
    TResponse Response { get; }
}
```

The error is

> Invalid variance: The type parameter TResponse must be invariantly valid on IHandlerTest<TRequest, TResponse>.Handle(TRequest). TResponse is covaiant

my purpose is to cast with this line of code

```
var cast = handlerConcrete as IHandlerTest<MessageBaseTest, ResponseMessageBaseTest>;
```

Comment: In short - it is not possible with tasks (and your generic response). variance is not supported for classes.

Comment: Thank you Guru, I changed GenericResponse in an interface and deleted Task in the response. I can avoid using Task. Now is it possibile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible for multiple reasons. First of all variance in C# is not supported for classes, hence neither `Task` nor `GenericResponse` can be used as return parameter for `Handle`. Latter could be workaround by introducing an interface - `public interface IGenericResponse<out TResponse> where TResponse : ResponseMessageBaseTest` but for `Task` it would not be so easy.

But the main flaw is that `new HandlerTestConcrete<MessageBaseTestConcrete, ...>` is not `IHandlerTest<MessageBaseTest, ...>` for quite obvious reasons - it requires "at least" `MessageBaseTestConcrete` to be passed in, so passing `MessageBaseTest` breaks this requirement. But using `MessageBaseTestConcrete` should work:

```
var cast = handlerConcrete as IHandlerTest<MessageBaseTestConcrete, ResponseMessageBaseTest>;
```

Or any inheritor (`MessageBaseTestConcreteConcrete : MessageBaseTestConcrete`):

```
var cast = handlerConcrete as IHandlerTest<MessageBaseTestConcreteConcrete, ResponseMessageBaseTest>;
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed GenericResponse in an interface and deleted Task in the response. but the error on    
GenericResponse<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request);
is the same

Comment: @user3401335 [compiles just fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4pct0s)

Comment: @user3401335 are you sure you have not missed `out` in the interface?